# Writing a Timer class in c++

Tags: c++, timer, sdl, c++-chrono

Since I have very little experience in issues like timing, I would like to ask you guys before taking my next step.
I am currently writing a game engine with SDL and use the function `SDL_GetTicks()` to calculate my deltaTime in the GameLoop.
Since I need a timer functionality for controlling the lifetime of assets (I want to remove the asset from the cache, when it hasn't been used for a specific amount of time) I looked for some ways to implement one.
I found the `<chrono>` header suitable for that task, but remembered that I already use `SDL_GetTicks()` internally for my deltaTime.

For me it sounds like using two different timers could cause some problems.
Is there anything I should watch out for, or simply just stick with `SDL_GetTicks()` for all timing issues?

P.S: I apologize if this belongs in the "Game Development" section, but I thought it's kind of a general question

Comment: Having a separate `std::thread`that sleeps for a certain time [`std::thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) might be what you're after. How does `ticks` convert to certain time units BTW?

Comment: It returns a number of milliseconds since the SDL library had been initialized. I'm not sure how I should use a sleep function for timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `std::chrono` would work in general for you except you can't use if for the tick count because you use `SDL_GetTicks()` for that information. Then why can't you just use `std::chrono::duration` with the result from that function?

> For me it sounds like using two different timers could cause some problems.
>   Is there anything I should watch out for, or simply just stick with SDL_GetTicks() for all timing issues?

Unless I'm missing something using `std::chrono::duration` doesn't involve more than 1 timer (i.e., you're still only using the `SDL_GetTicks` function to get timings). You're just using `std::chrono::duration` to store the representation of  the result returned by `SDL_GetTicks`.

### Example

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

// This function is only for illustration, I don't know what type
// the real function returns
long long SDL_GetTicks()
{
    return 1234567890;
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds elapsedTime(0);
    elapsedTime += std::chrono::milliseconds(SDL_GetTicks());
    std::cout << elapsedTime.count() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guess I should learn how to write more specific questions^^ Yes I know this attempt, what I actually wanted to know is, if there are any things I should watch out for when writing a timer class. Would vote up if I could^^

Comment: @EmeraldOverflow I tried to update my answer to address that part of your question. Unless I'm overlooking something I don't see any cause for concern. You're still using the 1 timer you're just storing the result of `SDL_GetTicks` in a different type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just looked up the cppreference more precisely and going to stick to that attempt.

Answer (score 4):

If it would be helpful to you (I really don't know), you can integrate `SDL_GetTicks()` into the `std::chrono` system by building a custom clock around it like this:

```
#include <chrono>

struct GetTicks_clock
{
    using duration   = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    using rep        = duration::rep;
    using period     = duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<GetTicks_clock, duration>;
    static const bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now() noexcept {return time_point(duration(SDL_GetTicks()));}
};

int
main()
{
    auto t0 = GetTicks_clock::now(); // has type GetTicks_clock::time_point
    // do something here
    auto t1 = GetTicks_clock::now(); // has type GetTicks_clock::time_point
    auto delta_ms = t1 - t0;  // has type std::chrono::milliseconds
}
```

Now you can use `GetTicks_clock` exactly as you would `std::chrono::steady_clock`.  This gives you a type-safe timing infrastructure (durations and time_points) all based on your existing `SDL_GetTicks()`.  You can even sleep or wait using your custom clock:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_until(GetTicks_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1));
```